# vim search and replace limited to the highlight in visual block mode

Tags: search, vim, replace

I often have text in columns and need to replace some things without clobbering similar stuff on the same line... a simple example follows:

[image: vim visual block-mode screenshot]

Suppose I have highlighted the text in grey with vim visual block mode, and want to replace `80` with `81`; however, I only want replacements within the highlighted visual block.

I have already tried <kbd>Cntl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `: s/80/81/g`; however, that replaces text inside and *outside* the visual block. (based on Randy's feedback, it's because `: s` is a line-wise command).

I know I *could* use a line-wise visual block replace in this particular instance ( <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `: s/80\.1/81.1/g` ); however, I'm trying to find a general solution for the problem of having no easy means to replace within a non line-wise visual block (isn't this the kind problem that visual block mode is supposed to help solve?).  Answers requiring confirmation like `: s/80/81/gc`, are not what I am looking for.

I will restate the question for clarity: How can I replace `80` with `81` by using vim's visual block mode highlight?

Comment: FYI... for those who use `gvim` under MS Windows, visual block mode is `<cntl-q>`, because `<cntl-v>` pastes the copy buffer

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to add `\%V` to your pattern.  From `:help \%V`:

```
Match inside the Visual area.  When Visual mode has already been
stopped match in the area that gv would reselect.
This is a /zero-width match.  To make sure the whole pattern is
inside the Visual area put it at the start and end of the pattern.
```

*OP EDIT*: the explicit solution is to to use `: s/\%V8\%V0/81/g`

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for; it's interesting that I don't need `\%V` in line-wise block mode.

Comment: Because ':s' is a linewise operation.  The advantage of adding this is that even if you left visual mode you can still operate on the last visual selection with '\%V' in your pattern.

Comment: For me to understand this I treat `\%` like a regex escape character, `\` and `V` like `b` in `\b` for a word boundary where `\%V` is the boundary of the selection.

Comment: @YzmirRamirez This way of understanding `\%V` is completely incorrect. `\%V` is a zero-width atom that matches *inside* the visual selection. If you select one character (e.g. `1`) and use `\%V1\%V` you will see that there is no match because second character is not inside the selection. Also if it *was* boundary using `\%V2` on selection `123` would not match `2`.

Comment: @MikePennington For the reason explained above your edit is not correct. Correct regex is `\%V8\%V0`, *not* `\%V80\%V`.

Answer (score 7):

The visual selection block [should](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace_in_a_visual_selection) be identifiable with %V

```
:'<,'>s/\%V80/81/g
```

Answer (score 6):

The solution is obviously the \%V regex atom, but note, that this it still a little bit buggy.

**Update**: It's no bug. This [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/vim_dev/l8uTRc43ETI/H6KN6YopFhMJ) explains the behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  What kind of buggy behavior have you seen with `\%V`?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt It would be more helpful if you a) said that `\%V` matches inside the regex (see my comment to the accepted answer) and b) deleted or unproved the above comment which states that `\%V` is not zero-width. // I think it is your edit that made this question appear in the RSS.