# VsVim: Replacing text within visual highlighted section

Tags: visual-studio, search, replace, language-agnostic, vsvim

Using [VsVim](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/59ca71b3-a4a3-46ca-8fe1-0e90e3f79329), I want to replace all instances of  `aaa` with `bbb` in the visual text highlighted area.

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6230494/vim-search-and-replace-limited-to-the-highlight-in-visual-block-mode), but specifically for VIM, not VsVim:

I've tried selecting the text, then typing

```
:'<,'>s/\%Vaaa/bbb/g
```

... but I get `Pattern not found: \%Vaaa`

I've also tried:

```
: s/\%Vaaa\%V/bbb/g
```

... with a similar outcome.

How do I replace all instances of `aaa` with `bbb` within the highlighted text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sort of seems obvious now, but here's what worked:

```
:'<,'>s/aaa/bbb/g
```

Any comments on the [use of %V](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8562184/vim-visual-selection-and-regexp) in VsVim are appreciated.